# differentiation under the integral sign conditions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to know that if I have $$\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_u^vf(t,\alpha)dt$$ 
and I want to using Leibniz's theorem calculate it.
How can I check the conditions of this theorem?
Example:$$\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_{\sin \alpha}^{\cos \alpha}\log(\alpha + t)dt$$ 
It accord with condition of the theorem or not? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the conditions for [Leibniz's Rule for Differentiating Under the Integral Sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).  For the problem of interest is

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_{\sin \alpha}^{\cos \alpha} \log(\alpha +t)\,dt&=\log(\alpha +\cos \alpha)\frac{d\cos \alpha}{d\alpha}-\log(\alpha +\sin \alpha)\frac{d\sin \alpha}{d\alpha}\\\\
&+\int_{\sin \alpha}^{\cos \alpha} \frac{d \log(\alpha +t)}{d\alpha}\,dt \tag 1
\end{align}$$

**provided the value of $\alpha$ does not render the theorem inapplicable**.

For example, if we are evaluating the integral in $(1)$ at $\alpha = \alpha_0 >-1$, then there exists a neighborhood of $\alpha_0$, for which $\alpha +t>0$, and in which the logarithm function and its first derivative are continuous.

Inasmuch as $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ are continuously differentiable for all $z$, then the conditions of the theorem hold and we can proceed according to $(1)$.